# How do I save a file using Pyplot within Azure Synapse Workspace?

Tags: python, azure, pyspark, azure-synapse

I am utilizing an Azure Synapse Analytics Workspace where I am running a PYSpark notebook from the Notebook tab of the workspace.

The workspace is also connected to an Azure Data Lake Storage Gen 2, which has a container called filesystem.

Usually to save files I write them in Spark using the ABFSS path after exporting my DataFrame.

```
UC_export=spark.createDataFrame(Error_Report.astype(str), verifySchema=False)
UC_export.coalesce(1).write.format('csv').mode('overwrite').save('abfss://[Container Name].dfs.core.windows.net/Assets_DQ/Error_Report.csv', header=True)
```

However for the following code, I have no idea how to save figures. How do I run a loop which can export the *.png files to the ABFSS container?

```
for error in Unique_Conso_df_check['Rule Broken'].unique():
    for column in suitable_columns:
        fig = plt.figure()
        ax = plt.subplot(111)
        pd.crosstab(Unique_Conso_df_Error[column],Unique_Conso_df_Error[error]).plot(kind='bar', rot = 90, ax=ax, figsize=[20,10])
        ax.get_figure().savefig(savedirectory+'/densityplot_'+str(column)+'.png')
        plt.show()
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to mount the storage account then you can use plt.savefig()
as explained in [this post](https://www.theanalyticslab.nl/save-any-type-of-file-from-azure-synapse-notebook-on-azure-data-lake-gen2/)

It only worked when I did not use plt.show()until after I saved the image.

```
mssparkutils.fs.mount("abfss://Container_name@account_name.dfs.core.windows.net/file_path/", "/mount_name", {"linkedService":"Your_linked_service"})

#here is my graph
plt.plot(x,y)

# retrieve the job-id 
jobId=mssparkutils.env.getJobId() 

# now save the image using the mounted path
plt.savefig(f"/synfs/{jobId}/mount_name/figure_name.png")
```